# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task.. Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using
Android Studio 3.1.2
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
Gradle version 4.4

I am getting following exception `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task.. Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException:`

I have tried all the answers available on StackOverflow but still getting the exception.

#### My build.gradle file contains following dependencies

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.estimote:sdk:0.9.4@aar'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by reinstalling the android studio and Gradle. Turns out the project I was working on required a particular version of Gradle and android studio.